# Angular is it possible to detect if query Paramter has changed?

Tags: angular, query-string

Angular is it possible to detect if query Paramter has changed? 
I have a Component that handles 2 query paramters and according to what paramter you come with it sets some variables true or false. The Problem is if im on my component with queryparameter 1 the qp can change to the second paramter without leaving the component and in that case i need to set variables diffrently. So how do I detect that? Is that even possible?

Comment: Is that even a required use case, I dont understand when do someone actually need a query param in angular. why cant u pass input to coponent

Comment: @JinsPeter direct link for instance ?

Comment: @JinsPeter If, for instance, your have some param to pass through your entire application (i.e. your url looks like `mydomain.com/#myParam/myRoute`), and for some reason you refuses to use global variables.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can subscribe to the params in the root component

```js
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.queryParams.subscribe(p => console.log(p.myQueryParam)); // you can also do this in ngOnInit
}
```

See also https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

You can have query params on other route levels as well, but then they are called matrix parameters.

See also the end of this section https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional

Comment: Glad to hear. The 2nd part was only additional information in case you didn't know about the difference between query and matrix parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to the **params** observable provided by ActivatedRoute module to observe changes in the query parameters.

```js
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params:Params)=>{
            console.log(params['yourId']);
    };
)}
```

Comment: `params` is for route params, not for query params.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your comment made me to understand

Answer (score 1):

In my case i wanted to reload page if **queryParams** changed to new...

**Router was:**

> tabs/home/product?id=1984

So I wanted to call **productDetails()** again if **id params** is changed!

**Solution**

```
constructor(){
 //Recive Product Id 
  activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((data) => {
    if (this.product_id != undefined && this.product_id != 
        data['params'].id) {
        console.log('we can reload page');
        this.product_id = data['params'].id
        this. productDetails()
   }else{
    this.product_id = data['params'].id
    }
   })
}
```

it Worked For me!
Hope it will Help :)