# Passing filter options to route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular 4 application there are several form fields that allows user to enter and select some filter options. There are form fields and not anchor links. I need to pass these options (all optional) to route and read it back to show result and populate form fields again.

This is very similar to filters in any shopping application. Please view the wireframe to understand it better. I don't want to use any plugin.

**Application Wireframe**

[image]

Comment: depending on how you bind your model to your form, using `ngModelChange` then making an api call is all you really need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set a filter options in the queryParams https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/ and then subscribe to see if the queryParams change and filter your data [Angular is it possible to detect if query Paramter has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003510/angular-is-it-possible-to-detect-if-query-paramter-has-changed).

You can also do it on the route guard if you change the policy of running your guards https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers. In your case it will be **paramsOrQueryParamsChange**.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Is it possible to use / instead & and ? for query params?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure, but probably not.